# Pop up android app

Tags: android, image, popup

I have a pop up that displays an image upon clicking a button. I got to display the pop up but the image is so small and I want it to occupy the 90% of the screen and add a close button to it.

Here is my code:

```
PopupWindow popUp;
LinearLayout layout;
TextView tv;
LayoutParams params;
ImageView imageView;
boolean click = true;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bmi);

    popUp = new PopupWindow(this);
    layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    tv = new TextView(this);

    imageView = new ImageView(this);

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.animalbite);

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    int fullScreenWidth = display.getWidth();

    int dialogWidth = (int) (fullScreenWidth * 0.9);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
    params.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    params.width = dialogWidth;
    getWindow().setAttributes(params);

    imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
    //tv.setText("Hi this is a sample text for popup window");
    layout.addView(imageView, params);
    popUp.setContentView(layout);

      Button ViewBmi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ViewBmi);

      ViewBmi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

             public void onClick(View v) {

                  if (click) {
                        popUp.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 10 ,10);
                        click = false;
                    } else {
                        popUp.dismiss();
                        click = true;
                    }


             }
             });

}
```

Here is the display:

[image]

ANy ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
PopupWindow popUp;
    LinearLayout layout;
    TextView tv;
    LayoutParams params,params2;
    ImageView imageView;
    boolean click = true;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        final int height = (display.getHeight()*90)/100;
        final int width = (display.getWidth()*90)/100;

        popUp = new PopupWindow(this);
        layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        tv = new TextView(this);

        imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        params = new LayoutParams(width,height-50);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.addView(imageView, params);

        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Close");
        params2 = new LayoutParams(100,50);
        layout.addView(button,params2);   


        popUp.setContentView(layout);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 popUp.dismiss();
                 click = true;
            }
        });

          Button ViewBmi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

          ViewBmi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                 public void onClick(View v) {

                      if (click) {
                            popUp.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 10, 10);
                            popUp.update(10, 20, width,height);
                            click = false;
                        } else {
                            popUp.dismiss();
                            click = true;
                        }


                 }
                 });

    }
```

Try This....

```
Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Close");
        params2 = new LayoutParams(100,50);
    --->params2.setMargins(100, 0, 0, 0);
        layout.addView(button,params2);
```

Comment: did not work for me. the image is gone and the popup still has the same size.

Comment: Thank you! Good fix. Simple and working. Another question. How can I position the close button?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
...
layout.addView(imageView, params);
```

This way the ImageView will be as wide, as possible.

If the underlying dialog is not wide enough, then you can set it's width also full screen:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
params.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
params.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

Or if you want it to be for example 90% of the screen, then:

```
// get the width of the whole screen
Display display = getWindow().getDefaultDisplay();
int fullScreenWidth = display.getWidth();


//then set 90% of it to the width of the Dialog:
int dialogWidth = (int) fullScreenWidth * 0.9);
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
params.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
params.width = dialogWidth;
getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

Comment: THere is a notice when I try to change it to FILL_PARENT. The field ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT is deprecated

Comment: The other one is MATCH_PARENT i guess, it's the same, you can use that as well.

Comment: Take a look at this: [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#FILL_PARENT)
FILL_PARENT got deprecated, now it encourages he developers to use MATCH_PARENT. But they are the same constant -1 value.

Comment: Yeah, I change both params as MATHC_PARENT and still got the same output. I think the problem is not there. I just don't know where.

Comment: do you get the dialog under the image as wide, as you want it to be?

Comment: I didn't notice that you updated your answer. I got an error on this line.   WindowManager wm = (WindowManager).getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE); WindowManager cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: Remove the dot after the casting. Or just use getWindow(). Sorry, i copied this from a bunch of old code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15652/discussion-between-bali182-and-ljpv14)

Comment: See my updated post. I changed the code. See if I'my doing it right. And I have and error at this line. WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE); The method get context is undefined for the type MyCLass.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
height = (int)(0.9*getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight());
params.height = height;
```

Comment: I think the image already resizes, But the popup container itself stays the same. any ideas?